# SQL - add days to a date in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with this fields:

```
Id int(11) pk, 
Start_date date, 
End_date date, 
type tinyint(1),
Frequency int.
```

I want to do a select on this table where start_date+frequency = @date(a variable date) until end_date(loop).

How do this with sql?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Variable date is (for example):

```
SET @date = '2017-03-30'
```

type can be 0 or 1:

- if type = 0 my query is :

  ```
   select * from table 
   where type = 0 and start_date <= @date AND end_date>=@date
  ```
- if type = 1, frequency is a field with an integer number(a interval of days). So I have to check if adding this value to start_date is equals to @date.

  - if yes, I have to return the current record
  - if no, I have to iterate this operation

    ```
    Date current = start_date + interval of 'frequency' days
    while(current < end_date){
    if(current == @date)
    (this is the record I want)
    else
    current+=frequency
    }
    ```

The result of query of type 1 can be more than one record. And finally I want to UNION the result of type 0 and 1 in unique select.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: SQL is a powerful language. If you do things the right way, you will hardly ever need a loop. Everything should be done set based. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Zack  check my edit, thanks

Comment: @PM77-1 check my edit, thanks

Comment: So, to put it in less *focussed on the wrong solution* terms, you want to determine whether the difference between `start_date` and `@date`, in days, is an integer multiple of `frequency`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes , exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment/confirmation below the question:

> So, to put it in less *focussed on the wrong solution* terms, you want to determine whether the difference between `start_date` and `@date`, in days, is an integer multiple of `frequency`? –

Looks like you want something like:

```
select * from table 
where
   start_date <= @date AND
   end_date>=@date AND
   (
     type = 0 OR
     (
        type = 1 AND
        mod(datediff(@date,start_date),frequency) = 0
     )
   )
```

Once we determined the actual requirement, above, and it was clear we just need to find out if one number is a multiple of another, we use `mod` to compute that. The rest of the structure of the `WHERE` clause essentially follows the bullet-pointed section of the question.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what each line does